# How do I read/input data in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, io

I'm used to .NET 4.0, but came across a situation where I have to revert to .NET 3.5.

In my 4.0 code I would rely on this to read my data:

```
var Data = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();
```

The above won't work in 3.5.  Does anyone know what is the equivalent in 3.5 that will allow me to read the data at 'FilePath' and put the data into an array?

The error I get in 3.5 is System.IO.File does not contain a definition for ReadLines.  This error does not appear when I change my project properties to a target framework of 4.0.  It reappears when I use target framework 3.5.

Comment: I know this isn't quite the answer you want, but to read TSV files a little more accurately you may want to look at the FileHelpers project - http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Tim S.  I added more info about the error up above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines.aspx) was added in .NET 4. Since you're using the whole `IEnumerable<string>` anyway, [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.ReadAllLines.aspx) could be used instead.

```
var Data = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

Well you can use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.ReadAllLines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead - that will read the whole file into a `string[]` rather than reading it line by line, but you're reading the whole thing into memory anyway due to the `ToArray` call, so it's just a bit less efficient than with `File.ReadLines`.

Answer (score 4):

`ReadLines` is .Net 4+. You should be able to use `ReadAllLines` instead.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var Data = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();
```

`ReadAllLines` is available in the .NET Framework 3.5. `ReadLines` lazily reads the lines of the file and is only available starting in the .NET Framework 4.0, but since you are converting the whole thing into an array anyway, `ReadAllLines` should suit your needs.